# Custom JMS Queue in WebSphere 7 to Delivery by Date

Tags: java, jms, websphere-7

We need to make a JMS queue in WebSphere 7 that will not deliver the messages to the MDB until a date specified in the message. How does one go about making such a custom queue or queue processor? I have so far not been able to find any related information.

We prefer to use the internal JMS provider, but if this is not possible, we would like to try with WebSphere MQ.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on your initial description this sounds like JMS 2.0 Delayed Delivery?

IBM MQ v8 implements JMS2.0 - what type of JMS application is sending the message? If it's a JavaSE application this could send this to a normal MQ queue with the delayed delivery option.  A any WAS instance could pick up the message.

Delivery is implemented in 'the sending side' so the version of receiving side isn't important.

M.

Comment: I am aware of that available feature with WebSphere v8, but we are stuck on v7. What I am looking for is some kind of extension point where I can wite a custom class to implement or override their queue message delivery system.

Comment: Afraid that there aren't really the extension points you are looking for; the only option would be to investigate some form of API exit (check the Knowledge Center),.

Or more simply use some form of extra processing logic in the form of a server side app.